# MySQL: How do you add new id column to the table, group by the old column?

Tags: mysql, group-by, auto-increment, alter-table

I am trying to add column `new_id` to the table in MySQL Workbench, but I want this `new_id` to be GROUP BY the `old_id`.

I tried the code below. The `new_id` is automatic increasing, but it is not group by `old_id`.

```
ALTER TABLE candidate
ADD COLUMN new_id int not null auto_increment UNIQUE FIRST,
ADD PRIMARY KEY(old_id, new_id);
```

Below is what I got:

```
+----------+--------+
| old_id   | new_id |
+----------+--------+
| 00132004 |    1   |
| 00132004 |    2   |
| 00132004 |    3   |
| 00132004 |    4   |
| 00118685 |    5   |
| 00118685 |    6   |
| J99999   |    7   |
| J99999   |    8   |
| J99988   |    9   |
| J99987   |   10   |
+----------+--------+
```

But this is what I *want to* get:

```
+----------+--------+
| old_id   | new_id |
+----------+--------+
| 00132004 |    1   |
| 00132004 |    1   |
| 00132004 |    1   |
| 00132004 |    1   |
| 00118685 |    2   |
| 00118685 |    2   |
| J99999   |    3   |
| J99999   |    3   |
| J99988   |    4   |
| J99987   |    5   |
+----------+--------+
```

What am I missing here....? 
Thank you!!!

Comment: An auto increment column will generate a new value for each new record. It will not (and shouldn't) generate a value that duplicates the value in a different row. If you really need something like this, you will have to create a before insert trigger and calculate the value to put in the column.

Comment: Autoincrement increments on each row. You can't change that. If you want a auto-incrementing non-unique id you'd likely have to write a custom function for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new requirement for `new_id` will not work making that column auto increment, because then the values will not be unique or incremental.

What you are looking for is something called the dense rank.  MySQL does not have built in support for this, but you can simulate it using session variables:

```
SET @dense_rank = 0;
SET @old_id = NULL;

SELECT
    @dense_rank:=CASE WHEN @old_id = old_id
                      THEN @dense_rank ELSE @dense_rank + 1 END AS dr,
    @old_id:=old_id AS old_id,
    new_id
FROM candidate
ORDER BY new_id
```

Note that because MySQL does not support any clean way of automatically having a dense rank maintained, a `SELECT` query might be your best long term option.  This way, you can just compute the dense rank from the latest data whenever you need it, without needing to worry about maintaining it in your actual table.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

What you want can (sadly) not be done with an auto-increment column.

An alternative solution could be:

```
CREATE TABLE mytab (new_id int not null auto_increment,
old_id VARCHAR(200),
FOREIGN KEY old_id (old_id) REFERENCES candidate(old_id));

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX old_id_idx ON mytab(old_id);
```

This guarantees unique old_ids and gives you a unique new_id in return. You can now join this new_id against the candidate table with an INNER JOIN and get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Add the column, then set it using `update`:

```
set @old_id = '', @rn = 0;

update candidate
    set new_id = if(@old_id = old_id, @rn,
                    if(@old_id := old_id, @rn := @rn + 1, @rn := @rn + 1)
                   )
    order by old_id;
```

Comment: Gordon, this might become burdensome if _new_ data were to be added to the table, because we'd have to run this update each time (potentially).